# How to stop audio with React use-sound module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the use-sound module in React and trying to make a play/pause button. The audio plays when I click the button, but I cannot stop the audio when I click it again.

I check in the console, and saw that clicking the button changes the isPlaying value properly, but the actual audio does not stop.

Does anyone know how to stop the audio? A million thanks!

Here's my code for the button, the "music" variable is the path the the audio file:

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import useSound from "use-sound";

const PlayBtn = ({ music }) => {
  const sound = music;
  const [play, { stop, isPlaying }] = useSound(sound);
  console.log(isPlaying);

  return (
    <span>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={["far", "play-circle"]}
        onClick={isPlaying ? stop : play}
      />
    </span>
  );
};

export default PlayBtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, Audio play and pause using hooks. Just edit and write functionalities according to your code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    const useAudio = url => {
      const [audio] = useState(new Audio(url));
      const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
    
      const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);
    
      useEffect(() => {
          playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
        },
        [playing]
      );
    
      useEffect(() => {
        audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
        return () => {
          audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
        };
      }, []);
    
      return [playing, toggle];
    };
    
    const Player = ({ url }) => {
      const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(url);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={toggle}>{playing ? "Pause" : "Play"}</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Player;
```

Answer (score 0):

Breaking `use-sound` package release 4.0 removes the `isPlaying` boolean; tracking that state was causing additional re-renders, which could pile up when using multiple instances of the hook.

If you were relying on this prop, you can implement it yourself using the `onplay` and `onend` events from Howler.

**Sample**

```
import React from "react";
import useSound from 'use-sound';
import Music from '../assets/audio/Music.mp3';

const MusicPlayer = () => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = React.useState(false);

  const [playBoop, {pause}] = useSound(Music, {
    onplay: () => setIsPlaying(true),
    onend: () => setIsPlaying(false),
  });

  const togglePlay = () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      pause();
    } else {
      playBoop();
    }
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Is playing: {isPlaying.toString()}</h2>
      <br />
      <button onClick={togglePlay}>Play sound</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MusicPlayer;
```